# Would a pulse dial telephone affect ADSL reliability/speeds?

Tags: adsl, telephony

I have set up ADSL in a Spanish property that has a single pulse dial telephone.  A DSL splitter has been used, and both the telephone and ADSL work.  ADSL speed in this area is poor anyway, so its difficult to get a factual answer by experimentation.

The ADSL speeds in the property are simply awful, and connectivity to ADSL is also sporadic.  Having removed the phone and tested speeds without it, there doesn't appear to be a *massive* difference, so this question is more a theoretical one.

Therefore, *could* a pulse dial phone negatively affect ADSL connectivity/reliability?

I'm trying to remove all potential issues before I approach the ISP, to avoid any engineer charges.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it in years, but it should be ok. Telefonica's network supports tone dialing so just get a modern phone.

The best place to start is to log into the DSL router and look at the line statistics; then you can see your signal/noise levels on the line. From that you can determine what your likely speed will be.

Do remember Telefonica have a habit it of make really bad cable junctions. I spent months diagnosing an issue like this many years ago and it turned out to be nothing more than a bad cable junction some distance down the street.

Comment: I'm convinced its a line problem, but need something concrete to throw at them so they can't pass the buck.  The manual makes no reference to viewing the line stats (http://bit.ly/2scfas3).  I'm ooking through the admin settings now but can't see anything yet...

Comment: Page 52 of the manual shows a menu option called Diagnosis. What does that show?

Comment: It contains two functions, **Traceroute** and **DSL test**.  The latter shows different PVC options and a test button, the output of the tests are https://ibb.co/hPTaLv , https://ibb.co/eL8s0v , https://ibb.co/gmY37a

Comment: You probably want to pickup a non-crippled router. Even something like a Dlink or Netgear DSL router will give you this information. El Corte Ingles used to sell these units or you can pick them up cheaply on Ebay. You want to get some line statistics so you can see whats really going on. If Telefonica is your provider, I would just call them and ask for an engineer install. Then their engineer can experience the problem directly.

Comment: I brought a TPLink router across, but despite the settings being entered correctly (AFAIK) it won't connect (says no connection) in the admin screen. I'll try Telefonica tomorrow before I do any shopping.